# UDP packet greater than 1500 bytes dropped

Tags: linux, networking, udp

I'm developing a tftp client and server and I want to dynamically select the udp payload size to boost transfer performance.

I have tested it with two linux machines ( one has a gigabit ethernet card, the other a fast ethernet one ). I changed the MTU of the gigabit card to 2048 bytes and left the other to 1500.

I have used `setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MTU_DISCOVER, &optval, sizeof(optval))` to set the `MTU_DISCOVER` flag to `IP_PMTUDISC_DO`.

From what I have read this option should set the `DF` bit to one and so it should be possible to find the minimum MTU of the network ( the MTU of the host that has the lowest MTU ). However this thing only gives me an error when I send a packet which size is bigger than the MTU of the machine from which I'm sending packets.

Also the other machine ( the server in this case ) doesn't receive the oversized packets ( the server has a MTU of 1500 ). All the UDP packets are dropped, the only way is to send packets of 1472 bytes.

Why the hosts do this? From what I have read, if I send a packet larger than MTU, the ip layer should fragment it.

Comment: Will the IP layer still fragment the packets if MTU discovery is on?

Comment: Doesn't the DF bit prevent that fragmentation?

Comment: Offcourse. So the sending host is expected himself to discover the MTU? Or does the underlaying library do that for him?

Comment: Thanks to all for the replies. I should add something about my experiment. I have tried with tracepath ( this utility do path MTU discovery ). I have setted the MTU to 4096 and when I start tracepath my own host says that the message is too long, so tracepath reduces the message size. However as far as the message passes the local host, no other host will signal the error. Tracepath will continue to send 4096 bytes long messages and the remote hosts will drop them happily without sending an ICMP reply back.

Comment: You need to remember that ICMP delivery is best-effort, not reliable, and also that many firewalls are configured to only allow ICMP echo packets and not other types.

Comment: I think this is what's happening.  But I have a doubt about my configuration too. I have connected a pc with a gigabit ethernet card ( MTU set to 4096 ) with a router that only supports fast ethernet ( so 1500 bytes frames at most ). Could it be the problem?

Answer (score 8):

I fail to see the problem. You are setting the "don't fragment" bit, and you send a package smaller than the sending host's MTU, but larger than the receiving host's MTU. Of course nobody will fragment here (doing so would violate the DF bit). Instead, the sending host should get an ICMP message back.

**Edit**: IP specifies that an ICMP error message type 3 (destination unreachable) code 4 (Fragmentation Required but DF Bit Is Set) is sent to the originating host at the point where the fragmentation would have occurred. The TCP layer handles this on its own for PMTU discovery. On connection-less sockets, Linux reports the error in the socket's error queue if the IP_RECVERR option is activated; see [ip(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/ip).

Comment: ICMP type 3 code 4 means "Fragmentation required, and DF flag set".  How you listen for that message on linux I'm not sure.  I believe that the ICMP payload contains enough information to match it to a particular socket, in which case you might get it as OOB data, if you've enabled that.  Or a future `sendto()` call may fail with `ECONNRESET`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I should set the IP_RECVERR flag and then search the error queue, right? I have simply tried to verify if sendto gives me an error, in which case I control if the error is "Message too long" and so reduce the datagram size. From what you say the thing doesn't work this way, right?

Comment: @Alex: No, this doesn't work. When the UDP package is sent, the kernel doesn't know that the receiver won't be able to receive it. Since you normally don't get a response in UDP in case of successful transmission, the send call returns immediately (or after only local error checking, such as missing network connectivity). I haven't tried IP_RECVERR, but yes, I think this is how it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I will try with IP_RECVERR.

Comment: No ICMP error message will be recieved if these two hosts are on the same subnet, because the IP layer on the recieving host with the smaller MTU never even saw the packet - it was discarded at a lower layer for being too large.  It is simply incorrect to have two hosts with different MTUs configured on the same subnet.

Comment: @caf: thanks for pointing that out. It's not clear whether the OP has this setup.

Comment: It seems to me that if you are sending UDP packet that violates  MTU on local interface, the kernel immediately returns the error from sendto() without bothering to post the reason on the IP_RECVERR queue. Not a pleasant feature :(

Answer (score 2):

That "DF bit" you're setting, stands for "Don't Fragment".  The IP layer should not be expected to fragment packets when you've told it not to.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** correct to run hosts with different interface MTUs on the same subnet<sup>1</sup>.

This is a host/network misconfiguration, and IP path MTU discovery is not expected to work correctly in this situation.

If you wish to test your application's path MTU discovery, you will need to set up multiple subnets connected by a router<sup>2</sup>, with different MTUs.  In this situation, the router is the device that will pick up the MTU mismatch, and send back an ICMP "Fragmentation Needed" error.

---

<sup>1. Well, technically, same *broadcast domain*.</sup>

<sup>2. The devices sold as "home routers" are really router/switches - they route between the WAN and the LAN, but switch between the ethernet ports on the LAN.  This **isn't** sufficient to separate networks with different MTUs.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So the "Fragmentation Needed" thing is relative to the IP layer. I should use a router or a layer 3 switch for the thing to work. I didn't know that home routers are dsl routers + layer 2 switches, I thought they would be able to work as layer 3 switches for the lan.

Comment: @Alex Vitale: Yes, that's right.  You can configure a machine with two NICs as a router for testing purposes.